# Button detection in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity

we are developing a a game in unity 3D . To play the game we need a number of instruments. we have given a set of buttons to activate the instruments: each button corresponds to a particular instrument. when a button is clicked, the texture of the corresponding instrument becomes the cursor. different instruments are to be taken at different stages of the game. Now how do we detect if it is a wrong instrument that is taken and then display an error message ? The player should be able to play further only after he clicks the button of the right instrument. how to accomplish this?

refered link :http://www.games.jocuri-unity3d.com/heart-surgery.html

Answer (score 1):

I played the game. Each of the separate games appear to be "maps" loaded in the same basic surgery game. Each "map" seems to have a pre-determined script that the player follows, or else.

Each button/tool is given a ToolID.

For the heart-surgery "map":

```
toolsNeeded = {1,3,2,6,3,5,1,0}; //Loaded from "map"
currentToolIndex = 0; //New game
while(patientAlive && surgeryIncomplete) //Wherever win/loss is evaluated
{
   currentTool = toolsNeeded[currentToolIndex]; //Do this next
   nurse.RecommendTool(currentTool); //Tell the player
}
```

During ToolClick():

```
   if (clickedTool == currentTool) //Correct tool?
   {
      activateTool(currentTool); //Apply new texture
   }
   else nurse.BeratePlayer(); //ID10-T error
```

During PatientClick():

```
   if (correctPointClicked) //Not hack-n-slash
   {
      nurse.GoodJobWith(currentTool);
      currentToolIndex++; //Next step/tool
   }
   else patient.MaimOrKill();
```

You also pick which room to perform the surgery in. In this phase, the three doors can be evaluated like they are "tools"; the toolbox just looks a little different.

Comment: sir its not clear......